# Плавное разворачивание блока

Tags: jquery

Вроде бы типичная ситуация, но не могу понять, как сделать на jQuery плавно разворачивающиеся текст? То бишь, мне нужен аналог slideToggle для блока, только часть текста видна, а часть закрыта overflow:hidden. Мне необходимо, чтобы остальное содержимое при клике плавно разворачивалось, затем при клике сворачиловалось. НАсколько знаю транзишн можно ставить на цифровое значение, а текст будет динамическим, то есть текст нужно ставить в auto

Comment: Чем не нравятся [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) и [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) ?

Comment: Это тоже самое, что slideToggle - они работают на display: block - none, а у меня overflow

Comment: Ну так а чем мешает после завершения анимации сделать свой стиль? Через `callback`.

Comment: Для того, чтобы установить анимацию, нужно конечное значение высоты, а оно динамическое

Comment: Значит пишите аналог. Давайте коды, которые уже есть, и нормальное оформление вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Можно записывать полную высоту (с учётом прокрутки) при помощи `js` в `css-переменную`.

Её нужно обновлять после событий, которые теоретически могут повлиять на высоту сворачиваемого элемента, например изменение размеров окна.

А дальше обычная смена класса при клике и `transition`:

```js
function calcDropdownHeight(){
  $('.dropdown-text').each(function(){
    var fullHeight = this.scrollHeight;
    $(this).css('--full-height',fullHeight+'px');
  })
}

$(window).on('load resize', calcDropdownHeight);

$('.toggler').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.dropdown-text').toggleClass('open')
})
```

```css
.dropdown-text{
  line-height: 1.2;
  max-height: 2.4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}
.dropdown-text.open{
  max-height: var(--full-height);
}
.dropdown-text p{
  margin: 0 0 1.2em;
}
.dropdown-text p:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.toggler{
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="toggler">Toggle Text</h3>
<div class="dropdown-text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, pariatur, eos, 
totam quasi sapiente dignissimos id quas officiis ea voluptatem voluptatum 
suscipit optio non consectetur ducimus hic placeat consequatur veritatis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, pariatur, eos, 
totam quasi sapiente dignissimos id quas officiis ea voluptatem voluptatum 
suscipit optio non consectetur ducimus hic placeat consequatur veritatis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, pariatur, eos, 
totam quasi sapiente dignissimos id quas officiis ea voluptatem voluptatum 
suscipit optio non consectetur ducimus hic placeat consequatur veritatis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Геннадий, поздравляю вас с первой десяткой! Надеюсь, что вы не остановитесь на достигнутом и будете радовать нас и дальше своими ответами.

Comment: Служу Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

можно поставить для блока с текстом max-height, например 40px, overflow: hidden, transition: max-height 300ms linear, а для раскрытого состояния установить max-height, например в 300vh

Comment: Это все равно задать высоту жестко. Впринципе, можно расчитать высоту блока при раскрытии на JS, но хотелось бы как то проще....типа slideToggle

Answer (score 0):

Вот как вариант из двух блоков, один контролит второй:

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<h3 onclick="$('#first').slideToggle()">Block one</h3>
<p id="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut consectetur ratione accusamus sequi velit. Architecto nostrum adipisci incidunt accusamus laborum.</p>

<h3 onclick="$('#second').slideToggle()">Block two</h3>
<p id="second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut consectetur ratione accusamus sequi velit. Architecto nostrum adipisci incidunt accusamus laborum.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вот еще через max-height, но не красиво закрывается. Есть задержка, можно задать хоть 2000px но будет дольше задержка.

```js
$('h3').on('click', function () {
  const obj = $(this).parent()
  obj.toggleClass('active')
})
```

```css
h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

div {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
}

div.active {
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Block one</h3>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut consectetur ratione accusamus sequi velit. Architecto nostrum adipisci incidunt accusamus laborum.
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Block two</h3>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut consectetur ratione accusamus sequi velit. Architecto nostrum adipisci incidunt accusamus laborum.
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Текст в один блок попадает динамически с админки, поэтому использование двух блоков недопустимо. Задача, чтобы бы часть блока разворачивалось.....

Comment: Ну тогда решение номер два